# Programmatically populate the choice field in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a Webpart, in that I need to replicate the dropdown with sharepoint list choice field.

So I need to display all the options in the choice field to my custom dropdown field in UI.

this should be a dynamic, we can add the new values in the sharepoint list choice field and it should reflect in webpart dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPFieldMultiChoice software = item.Fields[FieldNames.Software.Value()] as SPFieldMultiChoice;
StringCollection softwareChoices = software.Choices;
```

You can loop through `StringCollection` and set the dropdowns.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between     using SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)spList.Fields[fieldName];and using SPFieldMultiChoice

Comment: SPFieldMultiChoice is used when multiple selections are enabled .. i.e. checkbox based control