# SharePoint Online Display All Options in a Choice Field In A Custom Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, choicefield

Is there a way to fetch all the Choice Options of a Choice Field created in a SharePoint Online List and to display in a custom SharePoint Page(Inside Pages Library/Site Pages)?(Without the help of any webparts)

I am creating a Poll with graphical representation using JQuery and Javascript. **I need to display Poll questions in a custom made page**.
The questions of the Poll should come from a SharePoint list and the options(Answer list of the Poll) would be fetched from a choice field say Radio button type from the same list.
All the choice field options should be displayed for the users to select while participating in the poll.

I am getting results of Rest API calls for fetching records of choice field. But I need the field(the header) itself along with its options.

Comment: Dear Sunil, can you please share the scripts that you've written so far according to this portion of your post - **I am creating a Poll with graphical representation using JQuery and Javascript.?** Also, please consider visting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47824/465053) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7130819/465053) post. These posts might have an answer to your question.